# How to Convert string time to date object in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, datepicker

how to convert string time to date object

```
var time_t = "09:56 AM" ;
this.audit_time = new Date(time_t); 

//Error Invalid date
```

how do i correct it.please help me to solve this

Comment: Why do you expect "09:56 AM" to be convert into a date?  ;)

Comment: What will be the date after you convert time into the date?

Comment: @Sachin i want to bind this                                 <p-calendar formControlName="audit_time" dataType="string" showTime="true" hourFormat="12" timeOnly="true"></p-calendar>

Comment: you can get current date by this command  : new Date().getDate()

Answer (score 3):

You need also date part in your string (this will also work with PM):

```js
var time_t = "09:56 AM" ;
var dt = new Date("1990-01-01 "+time_t);

console.log(dt);

dt = new Date(new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10) + " " + time_t);
console.log(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var time_t = "09:56 AM";
var timeArr = time_t.replace(" AM", "").split(":");

var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(timeArr[1]);
d.setHours(timeArr[0]);

console.log(d);
```

Comment: with `new Date()` you are introducing seconds